# MySQL syntax error using Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I have the following prepared statement for sql  in Java :

com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@6e56103e:

```
INSERT INTO `game` (Id , GameStart ,Name, Lenght, MapVersion, Mode)VALUES(2502591,'2000-03-02 02:02:02','5x5 aptb wdw','00:55:48','DotA v6.75b.w3x','aptb ')ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Id`=VALUES(Id),`GameStart` = VALUES(GameStart),`Name`=VALUES(Name),`Lenght`=VALUES(Lenght),`MapVersion`=VALUES(MapVersion),`Mode`=VALUES(Mode).
```

When I execute it in Eclipse I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Id`=VALUES(Id),`GameStart` = VALUES(GameSta' at line 1.
```

But at the same time when I execute the same query in SQLyog I don't get an error. Rows are updated. What can be a problem? Thanks in advance

Code:

```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dota","root","root");
    PreparedStatement updateGame = null;
    String updatingGame = "INSERT INTO `game` (Id , GameStart ,Name, Lenght, MapVersion, Mode)" +
                "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)" +
                "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +
                "`Id`=VALUES(Id),"+
                "`GameStart` = VALUES(GameStart)," +
                "`Name`=VALUES(Name)," +
                "`Lenght`=VALUES(Lenght)," +
                "`MapVersion`=VALUES(MapVersion)," +
                "`Mode`=VALUES(Mode)";
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    updateGame=con.prepareStatement(updatingGame);
                updateGame.setInt(1, game.Id);
                Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(100,2,2,2,2,2,2);
                updateGame.setTimestamp(2,timestamp);
                updateGame.setString(3, game.GameName);
                updateGame.setTime(4, (Time) game.Time);
                updateGame.setString(5, game.MapVersion);
                updateGame.setString(6, game.Mode);
                updateGame.executeUpdate(updatingGame);
```

And on:

```
updateGame.executeUpdate(updatingGame);
```

I get an error

Comment: Please show the Java code you are using to insert. Looks like your parameters won't be inserted correctly.

Comment: String updatingGame = "INSERT INTO `game` (Id , GameStart ,Name, Lenght, MapVersion, Mode)" +
   "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)" +
   "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +
   "`Id`=VALUES(Id),"+
   "`GameStart` = VALUES(GameStart)," +
   "`Name`=VALUES(Name)," +
   "`Lenght`=VALUES(Lenght)," +
   ...
   "`Mode`=VALUES(Mode)";

updateGame.setInt(1, game.Id);
   Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(100,2,2,2,2,2,2);
   updateGame.setTimestamp(2,timestamp);
   updateGame.setString(3, game.GameName);
   updateGame.setTime(4, (Time) game.Time);
   ...
   updateGame.executeUpdate(updatingGame);

Comment: Please put that code in your question and format it properly.

Comment: Did it, sorry for putting it in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake. I should use only `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeUpdate(updatingGame)` ;, because if I use it with parameter, I will overwrite values whiten by

```
updateGame.setInt(1, game.Id);
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(100,2,2,2,2,2,2);
updateGame.setTimestamp(2,timestamp);
updateGame.setString(3, game.GameName);
updateGame.setTime(4, (Time) game.Time);
updateGame.setString(5, game.MapVersion);
updateGame.setString(6, game.Mode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you are using a `preparedStatement` you have to do it this way

```
String query="Insert into tablename (col1, col2) values(?,?)";
PreparedStatement stmnt = //get the statement
stmnt.setString(1, "col1val");
stmnt.setString(2, "col2val");
```

Comment: Yes I do it:
String updatingGame = "INSERT INTO `game` (Id , GameStart ,Name, Lenght, MapVersion, Mode)" +
   "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)" +
   "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +
   "`Id`=VALUES(Id),"+
   "`GameStart` = VALUES(GameStart)," +
   ...
   "`Mode`=VALUES(Mode)";

This is my String, and then I do like this:

updateGame=con.prepareStatement(updatingGame);
   updateGame.setInt(1, game.Id);
   ...
   updateGame.setString(6, game.Mode);
   updateGame.executeUpdate(updatingGame);
Whe I wrote the following PreparedStatement in my question I meant its value just before .executeUpdate

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a duplicate value on the primary key.

Follow the @chaitanya10 suggestion, use `PreparedStatement`

How is your knowledge about Object Orientation? As I can see you aren't using correctly encapsulation.

Comment: I did it, I commented to chaitanya10.

Comment: Are you using auto increment ? how did you calculate the id value ?

Comment: No I don't use auto increment. I get Id from another method. It is parsed from web page (for example for http://ru.iccup.com/dota/details/3018033.html it would be 3018033)

Comment: Ok, did you try to debug ? I bet that already exists and record with the same id value. Open the sql editor and verify if this is true. Is a web application? maybe you have concurrency problems.

Comment: No, the DB is empty. It is a desktop app. Moreover, even when I in SQLyog  add  record and then add this record again, it being updated. So it works.

Comment: updateGame.setString(3, game.GameName);

1 - you should use game.getGameName() 
2 - GameName is no correctly camelCase spelled, use gameName
3 - gameName is a private var 

this applay to all vars